# How can I improve spark query performance?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have a table in hive (hdfs) like this:

```
columnA -> string
columnB -> string
columnC -> date
```

myTable has 250 billion rows. I want to records from below query:

```
Select main.*
from myTable main, myTable sub
where main.columnA=sub.columnB
and main.columnB=sub.columnA
and main.columnC - sub.columnC between -60 and 60;
```

It means records around 1 minutes equal each other in columnA and B.

It is really slow in hive but I tried it on spark. It is also slow.

I have 300 node and 100TB ram. I give 350 partition to my spark and executor_per_node 1 ,executor.memory 50GB ,executor.cores 5

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use ORC or Parquet files? Can you partition the data by hour rather than use `between` query on minutes?

Comment: it is orc file format and data is in one partition

Comment: You seem to be doing a cross-join. Those are always slow. Can you try `SELECT main.* FROM myTable main JOIN myTable sub ON main.columnA=sub.columnB`, for example?

Comment: i want main.columnA=sub.columnB
and main.columnB=sub.columnA. Not just one condition.  And i need cross join to find what i want ( join key makes difference ?)

Comment: I think `cross join` is the problem. Can you explain what youre trying to achieve so we can see if its achievable in another way.

Comment: You can join on one column then use where statement to further filter the results. Otherwise, you're selecting all rows from both tables before any filtering happens

Comment: İf i use both condition i select less data but in your case the result is bigger then you sugest apply filter i m not sure it s faster